# Quantization Aware Training Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, neural-network, object-detection-api, quantization-aware-training

I'm using tensorflow's object detection api to train my own object detection model. Currently using ssd_inception_v2 on tensorflow 1.15. I've trained many models previously using this api but what I'm trying to do is improve my inference time. I want to try quantization aware training I've found out by adding those lines to config file I can do qat.

```
graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 48000
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}
```

Now my question is after I have done the training do I need to convert my frozen model to tflite in order to make use of 8 bit precision? Or if I use my frozen model directly would it use 8bit precision? If not how do I convert my pb to tflite and do inference on that?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I noticed that if I use the graph_rewriter and then I convert the frozen graph to tflite, the converted network still has the quantization/dequantization/fake quantization layers, and the inference time is really bad.